# Visual Studio SSDT Schema Compare - limited number of items in the MRU connection list?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-data-tools, schema-compare, mru

When using **Schema compare** -> **Select target** -> **Choose database** it seems like the list of recently used database connections is limited to show five entries. When adding 'New connection' an (apparently) random entry from the list is replaced with the new entry.

Can this limit be changed, so we can have e.g. 10 databases in the list?

This would be helpful, as we work with solutions with two database projects, and five different target environments, and each time we do a schema compare on a database, moving up the 'environment ladder' some entries are removed, forcing us to re-enter connection strings on a daily basis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked and it's hard-coded to 5 right now. There's no way around this, but I'll look into fixing it in a future release since this does seem too low.

Comment: Would love to see this as a configurable option. I work with 5 different environments and 10 DBs in each on a regular basis so this list cycles pretty quickly when I need to define new comparisons. Thanks for checking on this, Kevin.

Comment: @PeterSchott a configurable option would definitely be nice, but it's less likely to happen than us just upping the default number. The implementation cost means that it'd be less likely to meet the bar for improvements vs. other priorities, whereas just changing the number to 10 and verifying behavior on low-resolution screens and other test areas is a simple enough fix. I'll keep the request for configuration option on the backlog though.

Comment: I can definitely understand that. It's better than the current limits. Thanks for getting this into the backlog.

Comment: Thanks a lot Kevin! Looking forward to it :)

Answer (score 1):

After updating SSDT to newer version amount of possible stored connections increased.
[Press to download](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/dn864412)